# TypeError: Cannot set property 'decoder' of undefined

Tags: mysql, database, node.js

I am getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'decoder' of undefined in following code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

//database connection
connection = mysql.createConnection({host: 'localhost', user: 'root', password: '********', database: '*******'});
connection.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) 
  console.log(err); 
 else 
  console.log("Connected to MySQL");  
});

exports.GetAllBlogsFromDb = function(req, res) {   
  var blogid = 1;
  var ListBlogs = 'SELECT `blogname` FROM `blogs` WHERE `blogid`=? LIMIT 1';
  connection.query(ListBlogs, [blogid], function(err, ResultBlogs) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log("ResultBlogs");        
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and to solve it, just upgrade node.js

```
# npm cache clean -f
# npm install -g n
# n stable
```

I used node.js v0.10.2 and now it works fine with v0.10.26

Comment: Thanks for your response, but there was problem in database connection and I have fixed that now.